# $() = ^{−1} + ^{−2} + ⋯  + 1$ then $(())^2 = ()$ in $[]/⟨ ^ − 1 ⟩$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, coding-theory

If  $$ is a finite field with $q$ elements an $n$ . I need to prove that if $() = ^{−1} + ^{−2} + ⋯  + 1$  then  $(())^2 = ()$ in $[]/⟨ ^ − 1 ⟩$
I tried to prove it with induction but i am stuck.I would appreciate help
thank you

Comment: A simple way is to observe that in your quotient ring $x\phi(x)=\phi(x)$. This is obvious from the point of view of coding theory. After all, $\phi(x)$ represents the *all ones codeword*, and multiplication by $x$ corresponds to a cyclic shift. It follows immediately by induction on $k$ that $x^k\phi(x)=\phi(x)$ for all natural numbers $k$. The main claim follows from this, because in $\phi(x)^2$ you are adding together $n$ copies of $\phi(x)$.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem rewrites
$$\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)^2\equiv n\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\bmod{x^n-1}$$
i.e.
$$x^n-1\equiv n(x-1)\bmod{(x-1)^2}$$
or equivalently
$$(1+y)^n-1\equiv ny\bmod{y^2}.$$
This follows immediatly from the binomial formula.

Note that your finite field can be replaced by any commutative ring.

Comment: thank you so much.I finally understad it